# Get structure url

Tags: structure, sections

I have a structure set up like:

**What we do (set as a structure)**

- 2nd level page A

  ```
  * 3rd level page A
  * 3rd level page A
  ```
- 2nd level page B

  ```
  * 3rd level page B
  ```

I'm setting up breadcrumbs for this so it's

Home / What we do / 2nd level page A / 3rd level page A

This is what I have so far but I can't figure out how to get the entry section url working (what-we-do) which is set in the Entry Url format.

```
{% set crumbs = entry.ancestors|default([]) %}
{% if crumbs|length %}
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ NEED HELP }}"> {{ entry.section.name }}</a></li>
    {% for crumb in crumbs %}
        <li><a href="{{ crumb.url }}">{{ crumb.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What does `entry.url` give you?

Comment: The whole URL. I'm after the url that the structure adds to the level above the entry.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Using `{{ entry.url }}` will link to the section name you output with `{{ entry.section.name }}`.

Comment: {{ entry.url }} gives you the url of the current entry. ie /what-we-do/2nd-level/3rd-level I need just the /what-we-do part for the breadcrumb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've made this more complicated that it needs to be for yourself. Reading the Craft docs on [Outputting the Entry’s Ancestors in a Structure Section](https://craftcms.com/support/breadcrumbs#outputting-the-entrys-ancestors-in-a-structure-section) it looks like you can use the handle `.getAncestors()` method to output the entries leading up to the currently viewed entry automatically, and have access to their URLs.

Give the example a go.

```
{% if entry.level > 1 %}
  <ul class="crumbs">
    {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
      <li>{{ crumb.getLink() }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```